# Python execute if/else statement based on sys.argv passed on Command Line

Tags: python, if-statement, sys

I am new to Python and the syntax is really throwing me off. I need to execute a script in which I'd like to execute a function based on the arguments passed on Command Line. Following is the pseudo code:

```
import sys

...
Code
Authentication
Role Validation 
...

Arg[1]
Arg[2]
Arg[3]

if(Arg[3] !exist)
  execute Func1 with Arg[1] & Arg[2]
else if 
  execute Func 2 with Arg[1], [2] & [3]
```

Can someone guide me how to structure this in Python's world or if there is any other way to do it?

Comment: Why do you try to do some tutorials first?

Comment: Sounds like a model for ArgParse.. have a google!.. LMGTFY https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Amending to @drum: I suggest to focus on `sys.argv`, `len(sys.argv) < 4`, `def doing_this(a, b): ...`, `ìf`, `elif`, in the tutorials eg. on python.org - and then come back if you hit a wall. Coders here will then love to help you prepare / find the next wall ;-)

Comment: You should show the code you have actually written, whose syntax is confusing you. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: use something like this to iterate through your command line arguments: for key,value in vars(args).iteritems():

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use `sys.argv`, it's just a normal Python `list`, you can use `len` on it to check how many arguments were passed (remember, the `0`th element is the program itself).

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    func1(*sys.argv[1:3])  # * unpacking removes repeated references to sys.argv
elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
    func2(*sys.argv[1:4])
```

I'd recommend looking at something like [the `argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) though; it's more work to learn, but it means your scripts get `-h/--help` support automatically, which makes it much easier to use the script, without implementing a usage message separately, risking it getting out of sync.

Alternatively, if you are up for using third party packages, [`docopt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt) is generally praised as an alternative to `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for. `sys.argv` is the list containing your command line arguments. `sys.argv[0]` is typically the command you ran, so you're interested in the ones after that.

```
if len(sys.argv) == 4:
    execute Func 2 with sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2] & sys.argv[3]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
    execute Func1 with sys.argv[1] & sys.argv[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) will get you the arguments the script was called with e.g. if you run your script like this:

```
python script.py arg1 arg2
```

`sys.argv` will be:

```
["script.py", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

Also the builtin [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function will return the length of an array. So for the above example `len` should be `3`.

Knowing this you should be able to write your code.

If you struggle getting this to work here is a hint:

```
import sys
arg = sys.argv

if len(arg) == 3:
    func1(arg[1], arg[2])

elif len(arg) == 4:
    func2(arg[1], arg[2], arg[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing that does what you ask could looks at the length of the list given by `sys.argv`

```
import sys

def func1(a, b):
    print "func1", a, b

def func2(a, b, c):
    print "func2", a, b, c

if __name__ =='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        func1(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
        func2(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

You seem to have noticed the first arg is the program itself.
Think about what should happen if the wrong number of arguments is passed. 
Have a look at the `argparse` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)